# How to copy a group of layers from one document to another in Photoshop?

Tags: photoshop, layers

I have a couple of images with mostly the same setting. I've added a couple of layers (mostly adjustment layers) within a group and want to add the same group to the rest of my images.

Is there any way to copy a group of layers from one document to another in photoshop?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open both documents select the group you want to move and now you have 2 options:

- Right-click on the group (in the layers tab) and click "Duplicate Group..." Under "Destination" change the value "Document" with the target document (the one that will receive the Group). The layers will be aligned to TOP-LEFT.
- Drag and drop group of layers in the second document. The layers will be placed under the mouse cursor.

Answer (score 1):

Open both documents.

In the source document, select the group of layers you want to move, and drag them (from the layers palette) onto the other document.

Easier to drag/drop if you don't have windows displayed in tabs (use Window > Arrange > Cascade.